# Java springboot reactive combining mono

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-webflux

I am  writing a signup entry point, which want to return a dto with id and token. I have tried using flatmap instead of map in the controller,but the result is the same.The code have two part first is the signup(for saving and checking user) and second (find the user id).But
my problem is how  to map the the result ,which involve two mono variable.

The code:

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public Mono<AuthResponse> signup(@RequestBody user_info user) {
    return tokenService.signup(user)
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Error("signup not work")))
            .flatMap(token->{
                return userRespository.findByyUsername(user.getUsername())
                        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Error("finding fail")))
                        .flatMap(userInfo ->
                                Mono.just(new AuthResponse(userInfo.getId(),token)));
            });
```

AuthResponse:(dto)

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthResponse {
    private Integer id;
    private String token;
}
```

Error output:

```
 2023-02-05T02:45:41.539+08:00 ERROR 147274 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [c841e0d1-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/signup"

java.lang.Error: finding fail
    at com.springboot.sohinalex.java.Controller.apigatewayController.lambda$signup$1(apigatewayController.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.springboot.sohinalex.java.Controller.apigatewayController#signup(user_info) [DispatcherHandler]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContex
```

for reference:
signup function:

```
 public Mono<String> signup(user_info user)  {

            log.info("signup start");
            return Mono.just(user).doOnNext(System.out::println)
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()))
                         .flatMap(Monouser->{
                     Mono<Boolean> isuserexist=IsUsernameExist(Monouser.getUsername())
                             .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                             .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(false))  //no user found => can register
                             .mapNotNull(res-> res
                             );
                     Monouser.setPassword(  //encode the password
                                     passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
                     Mono<user_info> savedusr = respository.save(
                     Monouser).log();

                            return isuserexist.doOnNext(System.out::println) //check the username exist in my db
                                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException()))
                                    .flatMap(
                                    res->{
                                        log.info("start the map");
                                        if(res){
                                        log.info("error");
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            savedusr.subscribe();//execute the saving user
                                            log.info("check");
                                       return  reactiveAuthenticationManager.authenticate(
                                                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                                        user.getUsername(),user.getPassword()
                                                )
                                        ).map(this::generateToken);

                                    }
                                    }
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have change the signup service instead to return the Authrespond with nested flatmap inside the service and it return what i want.Use nested flatmap to get the two variable and return it. Here for you with reference,any advice is welcomed:
signup controller:

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public Mono<AuthResponse> signup(@RequestBody user_info user) {
    return tokenService.signup(user);
}
```

signup service:

```
public Mono<AuthResponse> signup(user_info user) {

            log.info("signup start");
            // convert IsUserexist to boolean
            
            Mono<Boolean> isuserexist=IsUsernameExist(user.getUsername())
                    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(false))  //no user found => can register
                    .mapNotNull(res-> res
                    );
            return isuserexist
                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Error("cant check username exist")))
                    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                    . flatMap(
                    nameExist->{   //check username exist 
                        if(nameExist){
                            log.info("repeated");
                            return Mono.empty();
                        } else
                        {
                            log.info("not repeat");
                            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));    //encode the password
                            return respository.save(user)
                                    .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Error("cant save user")))
                                    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                                    .flatMap(
                                    savedUser->{
                                        log.info("user saved with id: "+savedUser.getId());
                                    return   reactiveAuthenticationManager.authenticate(
                                                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                                        user.getUsername(),user.getPassword()
                                                )
                                        ). switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Error("cant auth")))
                                            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
                                            .flatMap(       //generate token
                                                auth->{     //return id and token
                                            String token=generateToken(auth);
                                            log.info("token generated");
                                            return Mono.just(new AuthResponse(savedUser.getId(), token));
                                    });
                                    }
                            );
                        }
```

Comment: That's the answer work for me